# Apache Reverse Proxy to IIS

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis, centos, reverse-proxy

CentOS 7 running Apache 2.4.6 is acting as the central front facing web server to the Internet. As such it has a few reverse proxy connections setup. They all point to other LAMPs and work great. However I have one IIS server running one of them .Net/ASP websites that just doesn't want to load properly. Using the config below on the Apache, the IIS website loads all of the html & css stuff.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SeverName example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /extDirectory/ http://internalserver/internalDirectory/

    <Location /extDirectory/ >
        ProxyPassReverse http://internalserver/internalDirectory/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

However it looks like there is a sessionID mishap per this screenshot while accessing site externally: 
[image: External-gets-error]

Compared to the accessing same site internally:
[image: internal-is-OK]

Apache log and what I can gather from IIS's log aren't showing any errors. The only error I am getting is when using IE's buil;t in developer tools and am seeing the "200 Authorization not found" , even though I am logged in successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this using Apache as the ASP.Net developer came through with a fix to their software. This is their reply and solution:

> Enterprise creates authorization tokens that are used to authenticate each request coming to the server. Every AJAX request must have a valid authentication token, or it will be rejected. Part of the token is the end user's IP address. If the IP address in the AJAX request is different than the original login request, then the token validation will fail and the AJAX request will be rejected. Enterprise v6.5.2 determines the end user's IP address by looking for three specific HTTP headers in this order: HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, REMOTE_ADDR. We think that the proxy server may be sending a different IP address for the AJAX request, which would then cause the token validation to fail and the AJAX request to be rejected.

Open Enterprise's web.config and near the top ADD this line right underneath the  element:

```
<add key="USER_HOST_ADDRESS" value="127.0.0.1" />
```

Save and close web.config, then restart IIS.

That is it. Turned out to be an ASP.NET issue rather than an Apache.